# How can I use for loop in the input file and in the output file names?

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcgis

```py
arcpy.management.FeatureToPoint("Spatial_Join_1", r"C:\Users\moh22006\Desktop\ARCGIS\ArcGIS\ArcGIS\Projects\MyProject100\MyProject14.gdb\Spatial_Join_Point_1", "CENTROID")

arcpy.management.FeatureToPoint("Spatial_Join_2", r"C:\Users\moh22006\Desktop\ARCGIS\ArcGIS\ArcGIS\Projects\MyProject100\MyProject14.gdb\Spatial_Join_Point_2", "CENTROID")

arcpy.management.FeatureToPoint("Spatial_Join_3", r"C:\Users\moh22006\Desktop\ARCGIS\ArcGIS\ArcGIS\Projects\MyProject100\MyProject14.gdb\Spatial_Join_Point_3", "CENTROID")

arcpy.management.FeatureToPoint("Spatial_Join_4", r"C:\Users\moh22006\Desktop\ARCGIS\ArcGIS\ArcGIS\Projects\MyProject100\MyProject14.gdb\Spatial_Join_Point_4", "CENTROID")

arcpy.management.FeatureToPoint("Spatial_Join_5", r"C:\Users\moh22006\Desktop\ARCGIS\ArcGIS\ArcGIS\Projects\MyProject100\MyProject14.gdb\Spatial_Join_Point_5", "CENTROID")
```

The input file names are:

```
"Spatial_Join_1"`
"Spatial_Join_2"`
"Spatial_Join_3"
"Spatial_Join_4"
"Spatial_Join_5"
```

and I save the output files as:

```
"Spatial_Join_Point_1"
"Spatial_Join_Point_2"
"Spatial_Join_Point_3"
"Spatial_Join_Point_4"
"Spatial_Join_Point_5"
```

respectively.

How can I use a for loop in python so that I do not need to update the name manually?

Answer (score 0):

Break the input file names into parts via `split()` then recombine them and inject your extra text.

```py
input_file_names = [
    "Spatial_Join_1",
    "Spatial_Join_2",
    "Spatial_Join_3",
    "Spatial_Join_4",
    "Spatial_Join_5"
]
output_pattern = r"C:\Users\moh22006\Desktop\ARCGIS\ArcGIS\ArcGIS\Projects\MyProject100\MyProject14.gdb\{output_file_name}"

for input_file_name in input_file_names:
    file_name_parts = input_file_name.split("_")
    output_file_name = f"{ file_name_parts[0] }_{ file_name_parts[1] }_Point_{ file_name_parts[2] }"

    arcpy.management.FeatureToPoint(
        input_file_name,
        output_pattern.format(output_file_name = output_file_name),
        "CENTROID"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [range](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) and string concatenation. I am using [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) here.

Here's the implementation

```
for i in range(5):
   arcpy.management.FeatureToPoint(f'Spatial_Join_{i}', f'C:\Users\moh22006\Desktop\ARCGIS\ArcGIS\ArcGIS\Projects\MyProject100\MyProject14.gdb\Spatial_Join_Point_{i}', "CENTROID")
```

Comment: It is not working. Could you please check again

Comment: @Hanif Try printing it or putting it in variable and passing that variable into your function. Like `following code:`

for i in range(5):
     spatial_join = 'Spatial_Join_' + i
     url = 'C:\Users\moh22006\Desktop\ARCGIS\ArcGIS\ArcGIS\Projects\MyProject100\MyProject14.gdb\Spatial_Join_Point_' + i
    print(spatial_join, url)   //if this is working then your function     arcpy.management.FeatureToPoint(spatial_join, url, "CENTROID")


If it still doesn't work, there is some other problem.